# Result of .sh script RUN from Dockerfile is not saved to image

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

After `RUN ["./run.sh"]`, a folder produced by `run.sh` is visible from inside the script but lost once Docker continues.

Expected behaviour:
I would like to have access to the **public/** folder, which is generated by the `run.sh` script.

Dockerfile

```
  ...
  RUN mkdir -p /opt/site
  WORKDIR /opt/site
  VOLUME /opt/site
  COPY . .

  RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./run.sh"]
  RUN ["./run.sh"]
  RUN pwd
  RUN ls
  RUN ls public

  FROM nginx
  COPY --from=build-stage /opt/site/public /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Script

```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  rm -rf public/ node_modules/ node_modules/.bin/ package-lock.json yarn.lock
  npm install
  ls
  touch newfile.txt
  npm run build
  ls
```

`ls` from inside the run.sh script after `build`. The **public** folder is present.

```
...
Generated public/sw.js, which will precache 6 files, totaling 197705 bytes.
info Done building in 44.842 sec
*ls*
Dockerfile
config
gatsby-config.js
gatsby-node.js
newfile.txt
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
postcss.config.js
public
run.sh
src
static
tailwind.css
tailwind.js
```

`ls` from inside the Dockerfile. The **public** folder is missing and trying to interact with it leads to failure.

```
Removing intermediate container 1692fb171673
 ---> 474d83267ccb
Step 10/14 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 7c351b151904
/opt/site
Removing intermediate container 7c351b151904
 ---> bae37da8b513
Step 11/14 : RUN ls
 ---> Running in 384daf575cae
Dockerfile
config
gatsby-config.js
gatsby-node.js
package-lock.json
package.json
postcss.config.js
run.sh
src
static
tailwind.css
tailwind.js
Removing intermediate container 384daf575cae
 ---> 1f6743a4adc1
Step 12/14 : RUN ls public
 ---> Running in 7af84c5d72a0
ls: cannot access public: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c ls public' returned a non-zero code: 2
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2
```

Comment: i have added `newfile.txt` as a test for precisely this issue

Comment: do you build it by using docker or docker-compose ?

Comment: It is run from a gitlab-ci.yml file. the command is `docker build` https://git.finnfrotscher.com/finnfrotscher/finnfrotschercom/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a volume with the selected directory:

```
  VOLUME /opt/site
```

When defined in an image, a volume will get created for every container created from that image. If you do not specify a source for the volume (which you cannot at build time), docker will create an anonymous volume. And with both a named and anonymous volume, docker will initialize the contents to that of the image at that location.

The result of a RUN command is the following:

- create a temporary container
- that temporary container runs your requested command and verifies the exit code before continuing
- if successful, docker captures the result of a diff between the image and container. This is mainly the container specific read/write filesystem layer. However it does not include any external volumes.

This behaviour is [documented by docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes):

> - **Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile:** If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

**My standard recommendation is to remove any volume definition from the Dockerfile.** If you need a volume, define it at runtime with something like a docker compose file. This allows the image to be extended, and prevents anonymous volumes from cluttering the filesystem.

Comment: thank you. just removing the `VOLUME /opt/site` was enough to make it work.